# Splitting a message

Tags: array

I have a string to be splitted into define chunks.

For example `new_str="abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, and my goal is to split it to chunks of `split_size=5`, so the result should be :`abcde`,`fghij` and so o.

`new_str` gets every time a different string.

`split_size` can be any size.

I have 2 questions:

1) Attached code does the job, but looks a BIT not elegant for a newbie like me. is there another way doing it ?

2)In code attached, output is `Serial.println(tmp)` and should be replaced with an output function to post each chunk to as a MQTT message. Ive rather that each chunk would be stored into a global array, to be sent later on in code out side `msgSplitter`.

So I wrote the following code:

```
int split_size=5;
char new_str[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
void setup() {

        Serial.begin(9600);
        Serial.print("String length: ");
        Serial.println(strlen(new_str));
        Serial.print("Split Size: ");
        Serial.println(strlen(split_size));

        msgSplitter(new_str, split_size, "Split #");

}
void msgSplitter( const char* msg_in, int chop_size, char *prefix){
        num=ceil((float)strlen(msg_in)/chop_size);
        char tmp[50];
        int pre_len;

        if (num > 1) {
                for (int k=0; k<num; k++) {
                  pre_len=0;
                        sprintf(tmp,"%s %d: ",prefix,k);
                        pre_len = strlen(tmp);
                        for (int i=0; i<chop_size; i++) {
                                tmp[i+pre_len]=(char)msg_in[i+k*chop_size];
                                tmp[i+1+pre_len]='\0';
                        }
                        Serial.println(tmp);
                }
        }
        else {
                Serial.println(msg_in);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// concat version
void msgSplitter(const char* msg_in, int chop_size, char *prefix) {
  char tmp[50];
  int size = strlen(msg_in);
  for (int pos = 0, k = 0; pos < size; pos += chop_size) {
    int l = sprintf(tmp, "%s %d: ", prefix, k++);
    strncat(tmp + l, msg_in + pos, chop_size);
    Serial.println(tmp);
  }
}

// only value version
void msgSplitter(const char* msg_in, int chop_size, char *prefix) {
  char tmp[chop_size + 1];
  tmp[chop_size] = 0;
  int size = strlen(msg_in);
  for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos += chop_size) {
    strncpy(tmp, msg_in + pos, chop_size);
    Serial.println(tmp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you answer my 2nd cquestion ?

Comment: the second version of the function in my answer is it. replace println with the publishing function

Comment: You Rock Juraj!

Comment: U2 :) ( cough cough )